# Getting a # out of your url in PHP

Tags: php, url, get

I know that `$_GET["whatever"]` gets `?whatever=*`

Is there a way to get the `#` variable out of the url:

```
www.*.com#imsomething
```

? Can't find any results on google.

Comment: You want the bit after the # gone, or you want it returned so you can use it for something?

Comment: Can't. The `#` ([Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)) portion is never sent by the browser to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part after # is a client-side part of the URL, it refers to an anchor within the HTML. Therefore, you can only retrieve everything before that.

> Clients are not supposed to send URI-fragments to servers when they retrieve a document, and without help from a local application fragments do not participate in HTTP redirections.

~ Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

---

You can use this Javascript code to get it's content client-side:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

After grabbing it, you can of course send it to your server side code using jQuery's $.ajax or something similar.

Comment: <script language = "javascript">
                var anchor = window.location.hash;
                if(anchor == "#xpages"){
                 //do ajax call to php script that 301 redirects.    
                }  
            </script>

Will this trigger a 301.. or will ajax not know what to do with it?

I don't want a 402 redirect using javascript.

Comment: If you use something like $.ajax or $.get, it will return the contents of the page it was redirected to - the page your javascript is on won't be redirected

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not, since that is never sent to server side. That is something that is only visible on the browser.

You can read it with javascript and then submit to server side if you really want to, but normally it doesn't get sent. With javascript, you can read window.location.hash to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible with a server side language... You need JavaScript to read that.

Comment: @JamesT self.document.location.hash, self.document.location.hash.substring(1) if you want the value returned without the hash.

Comment: @JamesT if you really want the hash to be processed in the server side (PHP), you can go for Ajax... window.location.hash will give you hash text in URL in JavaScript and you need to send it through Ajax to a PHP page to process it.